# Why does the installer make an extended partition for swap by default?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap, mbr

Every time I've done a clean default install of Ubuntu or a variant on an MBR type system, I end up with a system partition and a swap partition.  The installer always tucks the swap partition inside an extended partition.

Why?  It seems more straightforward to create two simple partitions.  But I am guessing that there is a good reason and I am showing my ignorance here.

Answer (score 0):

Primary partition is only needed when you want to make it bootable. If you look up wikipedia there's a "full story" about that. Extended and logical partitions have some cons. But if you want a primary swap partition, you can partition it by yourself, it's not hard and you seem like you understand what are you talking about, so it shouldn't be a problem for you. There's a manual partitioning in most installers, or you can use GParted, fdisk, disked and others.

Hope this helps **:)**

Comment: Primary partition is not needed for booting. All major OSes nowadays can boot from logical partition without problem. Only ancient ones like XP or 9x suffer from this

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create partitions for Ubuntu installations.

Default is primary /, and swap in a logical one.

It does not matter for linux which type of partition to boot from (logical or primary).

The reason why this layout has been chosen must be that it is not always possible to create 2 primary partitions, when system is installed in parallel with some other OS, like Windows.

There is a limit in MBR of 4 primary partitions.

I would choose in this case to create an extended and two logical for / and swap instead.

Anyway this is just a default layout, you can change it as you like.